# Can not draw after onPause/onResume

Tags: android

I am writing my first android game. It is working fine in almost every respect, but when the screen timeout kicks in and I press the button to get back to the game, I find the image of the game state frozen. It appears the main thread is still alive - I can tell this because I have a set of sounds that occur when I drag certain objects around the screen, and the sounds still behave as if everything was working (except that I see nothing other than the frozen screen). If I then select a menu to show the "high scores" activity and then exit back to the game, I find all is well and can continue with all the graphics working properly.

I am not quite sure what parts of my code it is necessary to include in order to diagnose this problem, but here is my guess - I will add more if requested:

**EDIT:** On the advice of Brigham I have made a couple of mods to the code, but the symptoms are the same.

**EDIT:** I have noticed that if I click a button to instigate a "view high scores" activity then surfaceDestroyed() gets called. But when the screen timeout kicks in, surfaceDestroyed() is *not* called.

**EDIT:** There have been an awful lot of views of this question without a solution - I presume the problem must be quite tricky - or perhaps not revealed within the code snippets I've posted. Some suggestions as to how I might *diagnose* this problem would be extremely useful.

**EDIT:** I have now placed the entire (simplified) project in simple.zip and put it on the web at: http://dl.dropbox.com/u/2969211/Simple.zip - the critical code is all in the file simple.java

```
    MicksPanelThing mpt = null;
    public MicksThreadThing micks_thread_thing = null;

    @Override
    protected void onPause() // pair with onResume
    {
        super.onPause();
        allow_draw.set(false);
        micks_thread_thing.setRunning(false);
        save_state();
    }


    @Override
    protected void onResume() // pair with onPause
    {
        super.onResume();
        get_state();
        mpt.get_a_new_thread_all_over_again();
        micks_thread_thing.setRunning(true);
        allow_draw.set(true);
    }

////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

    public class MicksPanelThing extends SurfaceView implements SurfaceHolder.Callback
    {
        public MicksPanelThing(Context context) 
        {
            super(context);
        }

        public void get_a_new_thread_all_over_again()
        {
            getHolder().addCallback(this);
            micks_thread_thing = new MicksThreadThing(getHolder(), this);
            setFocusable(true);        
        }

        @Override
        public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) 
        {
            synchronized (micks_thread_thing.getSurfaceHolder()) 
            {
                if (event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN) 
                {
                    // blah
                }
                if (event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE && selected_node != -1) 
                {
                    // blah
                }
                if (event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_UP) 
                {
                     // blah
                }
                return true;
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onDraw(Canvas canvas) 
        {
            canvas_width = canvas.getWidth();
            canvas_height = canvas.getHeight();

            if (allow_draw.get())
            {   
                canvas.drawBitmap(sandy_bitmap, 0, 0, null);                

                // blah
            }

        }

        public void surfaceCreated(SurfaceHolder holder) 
        {
            micks_thread_thing.setRunning(true);
            micks_thread_thing.start();
            we_have_a_surface = true;
        }

        public void surfaceDestroyed(SurfaceHolder holder) 
        {
            boolean retry = true;
            micks_thread_thing.setRunning(false);
            while (retry) 
            {
                try 
                {
                    micks_thread_thing.join();
                    retry = false;
                    micks_thread_thing = null;
                } 
                catch (InterruptedException e) 
                {
                    // we will try it again and again...
                }
            }
            we_have_a_surface = false;
        }
    }

    class MicksThreadThing extends Thread 
    {
        private SurfaceHolder surf_holder = null;
        private MicksPanelThing micks_panel_thing;
        private boolean this_thread_is_currently_active = false;

        public MicksThreadThing(SurfaceHolder surfaceHolder, MicksPanelThing mpt) 
        {
            surf_holder = surfaceHolder;
            micks_panel_thing = mpt;
        }

        public void setRunning(boolean set_run) 
        {
            this_thread_is_currently_active = set_run;
        }

        public SurfaceHolder getSurfaceHolder() 
        {
            return surf_holder;
        }

        @Override
        public void run() 
        {
            Canvas c;
            while (this_thread_is_currently_active) 
            {
                c = null;
                try 
                {
                    c = surf_holder.lockCanvas(null);
                    synchronized (surf_holder) 
                    {
                        micks_panel_thing.onDraw(c);
                    }
                } 
                finally 
                {
                    if (c != null) 
                    {
                        surf_holder.unlockCanvasAndPost(c);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }

public class Allow_draw
{
    private boolean draw;

    Allow_draw()
    {
        draw = false;
    }
    public void set(boolean x)
    {
        synchronized (this)
        {
            draw = x;
        }
    }
    boolean get()
    {
        synchronized (this)
        {
            return draw;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Your problem is that you are keeping your `surf_holder` as your thread member witch is wrong. When your activity goes to sleep and then return the surface holder is changing, and it can also happen on screen rotation or other SurfaceView events. So the best practice will be to ask it from the view each time you are going to draw.

```
@Override
        public void run() 
        {
            Canvas c;
            while (this_thread_is_currently_active) 
            {
                c = null;
                try 
                {
                    Final SurfaceHolder holder = getHolder();
                    c = holder.lockCanvas(null);
                    if(c != null)// may happen when SurfaceHolder is changing
                        synchronized (surf_holder) 
                        {
                            micks_panel_thing.onDraw(c);
                        }
                    }
                } 
                finally 
                {
                    if (c != null) 
                    {
                        surf_holder.unlockCanvasAndPost(c);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
```

---

No no no no! You did it wrong!

Remove all the referances you got of SurfaceHolder, do not save it anywhere, remove that function you are using to get the holder, remove it from your thread too!. Only when you are about to lock the canvas do this:

```
//inside surfaceView
    public void updateView(){
        final SurfaceHolder holder = getHolder();

        try{
        Canvas canvas = holder.lockCanvas();
        if(canvas != null){
            onDraw(canvas);
        }
        holder.unlockCanvasAndPost(canvas);
        }
        catch (Exception e) {
            // TODO: handle exception
        }
    }
```

Comment: I presume you meant to use surf_holder rather than holder, and getSurfaceHolder rather than getHolder... but then surf_holder is out of scope for the line surf_holder.unlockCanvasAndPost(c); I tried putting the declaration of the surf_holder just within the while loop but then still have surf_holder = getSurfaceHolder(); within the try block... but the bug behaves exactly as before :-(

Comment: I still have several problems. How about you make the edits to simple.java (see link in OP), email it to me as an attachment. Then I will edit your answer here on StackOverflow and mark it as correct so you will get the bounty.

Comment: I uploaded the simple file. Check it out. [link](http://www.2shared.com/file/ttcRATsw/Simple.html)

Comment: Just uploaded and compiled your code. Sadly the bug is still there, exactly as before :-( but thankyou for trying.

Answer (score 2):

Your `MicksThreadThing` instance is dying after you call `setRunning(false)` in `onPause` because the `while` loop condition goes to false, and the `run` method exits.

You should either create a new `MicksThreadThing` in `onResume` or use some sort of synchronization to pause the run method until the user resumes the game. I recommend the `CountDownLatch` class to accomplish this. It would allow your `run` method to call `countDownLatch.await()`, at which point the thread would pause until you call `countDownLatch.countDown()` in the `onResume` method.

Also, the `this_thread_is_currently_active` variable should be made `volatile`:

```
private volatile boolean this_thread_is_currently_active = false;
```

Comment: "You should either create a new MicksThreadThing in onResume" - but I thought that was what I was doing already with: if (micks_thread_thing == null) { mpt.get_a_new_thread_all_over_again(); }

Comment: That only happens if it gets set to null at some point. Where is it getting set to null?

Comment: I see that now. Make sure `surfaceDestroyed` is being called, and add a log statement in onResume to be sure that `micks_thread_thing` is null.

Comment: after setRunning(false) has been executed, does the micks_thread_thing object still exist (albeit not running) - i.e. do I need to just get it running again or do I need to create a new one?

Comment: It still exists, but once the run method has exited, a Thread object cannot be started again. You will have to create a new one.

Comment: see mods to original question

Answer (score 0):

Try this:
In your Surface Destroyed method add this:

holder.unlockCanvasAndPost(MainThread.canvas);

EDIT:

```
@Override
public void surfaceDestroyed(SurfaceHolder holder) {
    Log.d("SURFACEDESTROYED","TRUE");
    boolean retry = true;
    while (retry) {
        try {
            holder.unlockCanvasAndPost(MainThread.canvas);
            thread.setRunning(false);
            thread.join();

        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }
}
```